# C++ - Implement Merging of graph nodes using Dereference operator overloading

Tags: c++, graph, operator-overloading

I have to work with Discrete graphs. And one particular procedure for me is to find strongly connected components of the graph. After which I have to merge equivalent nodes. That is, if there are the following nodes :- node1,node2,node3, etc. Eventually I need to be able to merge a few of them. For instance if node1 is a leader, node2, node3 should eventually be pointing to node1. So that, if node2 is accessed, instead we should get access to node1. (in any case they are equivalent).

One rough idea I had was to use a pointer to a node leader in each node. Initially it points to itself,but eventually it may point to a leader. And after that, if the node is accessed, we get access to the leader. (this approach may not lead to what I require, but I was just thinking of the possibilities).

So here is a basic node structure in C++ :- I would like to know how I should overload the dereference operator properly to get what I want :-

```
class Node{


    Node * leader ; 
    int data;

public:
    Node(int x):data(x),leader(this){}
    void display(void){std::cout << data << std::endl;}
    void setRoot(Node * newLeader){leader = newLeader;}
    Node& operator* () { return *leader; }
};
```

But I think I am doing the overloading wrong, as I do not get what I expect from the output :-

```
main(){

Node * ptr1 = new Node(1);
Node * ptr2 = new Node(2);


std::cout << "ptr1 data :- " << std::endl ;
ptr1->display();



std::cout << "ptr2 data :- " << std::endl ;
ptr2->display();

std::cout << "changing leader for ptr1" << std::endl;
ptr1->setleader(ptr2);

std::cout << "ptr1 data :- " << std::endl ;
ptr1->display();



std::cout << "ptr2 data :- " << std::endl ;
ptr2->display();


}
```

Output :-

```
ptr1 data :- 
1
ptr2 data :- 
2
changing Leader for ptr1
ptr1 data :- 
1
ptr2 data :- 
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it wrong here. The dereference operator could not be overloaded for a raw pointer. It could be overloaded for a newly defined class. Thus, in such situations it's better to use a wrapper for a pointer to the class instead of a raw pointer.

Here's the modified code which works and does what I wanted to do in the above question :-

```
class Node{


Node * leader ; 
int data;

public:
    Node(int x):data(x),leader(this){}
    void display(void){std::cout << data << std::endl;}
    void setleader(Node * newleader){leader = newleader;}
    Node * getleader(void){return leader;}
};

class NodePtr{

Node * ptr;

public:
    NodePtr(Node * node):ptr(node){}
    Node* operator->() {
        return ptr->getleader();
    }

};



main(){

NodePtr ptr1( new Node(1));
NodePtr ptr2( new Node(2));

std::cout << "ptr1 data :- " << std::endl ;
ptr1->display();
std::cout << "ptr2 data :- " << std::endl ;
ptr2->display();

std::cout << "changing leader for ptr1" << std::endl;
ptr1->setleader(ptr2->getleader());

std::cout << "ptr1 data :- " << std::endl ;
ptr1->display();    
std::cout << "ptr2 data :- " << std::endl ;
ptr2->display();


}
```